# TO-DO-LIST React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

how to choose false into true (or exact opposite) in the **CASE** *Edit Status*.

[It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.]

```
import React from 'react'
import shortid from 'shortid';

const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK'
const EDIT_STATUS = 'EDIT_STATUS'
const TASK_DELETE = 'TASK_DELETE'

const initialState = {
    tasks: []
};


const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TASK: {

            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: [{
                    id: shortid.generate(),
                    task: action.task,
                    status: false
                }, ...state.tasks]

            }

        }

        case EDIT_STATUS: {
            return {

            }
        }


    default:
        return state
    }
}

export const addTask = task => ({type: 'ADD_TASK', task});
export const editStatus = id => ({type: 'EDIT_STATUS', id})



export default mainReducer;
```

Comment: how to choose status ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to do that, but it looks like you search for logic at reducer to make this feature work

---

```
    case EDIT_STATUS: {
        return {
          ...state,
          tasks: state.tasks.filter(task => task.id == action.id ? {...task, status: !task.status} : task
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return {
    ... state, 
    tasks: state.tasks.map(t => (t.id === action.id
        ? {
           ...t,
            status: !t.status,
        } : t)), 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unclear of the complete implementation. From the question, I am assuming you want to toggle the status of the task between true and false, for the task id provided in the payload of EDIT_STATUS action. According to me, the below code could be a possible implementation.

```
case EDIT_STATUS: {
       return {
           ...state,
           tasks: tasks.map(task => {
              if(task.id == action.id) {
                 task.status = !task.status
              }
              return task
           })
       }
 }
```